# How to know when its not safe to open a Realm on iOS

Tags: ios, realm

From current list of "[Realm Limitations](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#current-limitations)":

> Any single Realm file cannot be larger than the amount of memory your
>   application would be allowed to map in iOS

Does this mean that if I check `ProcessInfo.processInfo.physicalMemory` and it is smaller than `FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath:realmPath)[FileAttributeKey.size]` (plus a variable amount to account for fragmentation etc), I should not try to open the Realm?

Answer (score 0):

If the Realm file is too big for `mmap` to map the file, you should get a Swift error. So all you really need to do is to `try` opening the Realm and catch any `Realm.Error.addressSpaceExhausted` errors.

The bigger problem is what to do once you know the file is too big. Our compaction on launch feature requires that the file be openable first, which rules it out (and is why we recommend that compact on launch be used to pre-empt this issue). We're working on ways to mitigate this problem.

`mmap` shouldn't depend upon the amount of free physical RAM you have (although some amount of RAM is required to map the file), nor is the limit that iOS imposes anywhere near the theoretical maximum. Finally, virtual memory limits operate on a per-process basis, meaning that the size of a Realm file you can open depends both on what other files have been mapped by that process and by how much memory that process is using for other things.

Comment: Hi, what you said in second paragraph means if I add the `shouldCompactOnLaunch` block, I won't have the `addressSpaceExhausted` error?